# Migration from Jboss7 to Wildfly: allow access to servlet only from specific IPs

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly

I'm migrating an application from JBoss7 to Wildfly.

On JBoss I was allowing the access to one of the servlet from specific IPs using the `valve` element in jboss-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
  <context-root>/test-war</context-root>
  <valve>
    <class-name>org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve</class-name>
    <param>
      <param-name>allow</param-name>
      <param-value>127\..*\..*\..*,0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0</param-value>
    </param>
  </valve>
</jboss-web>
```

I would like to reproduce this functionality in wildfly but I cannot find an equivalent function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Undertow, a new webserver in WildFly, doesn't support Valves (which come from Tomcat).

If you don't need to do filtering on a server level (i.e. if the deployment level is sufficient), then you can simply implement servlet Filter with the same functionality. This is portable solution covered by Servlet specification.

Look at [simple filter example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Servlets/IPFilter.htm) with hardcoded IP range.