# Wildfly8: Server-level Remote IP Address filtering with Undertow?

Tags: wildfly, undertow

How can I only allow requests from my Apache Server in the DMZ access to WildFly over AJP, and block everything else?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921533/migration-from-jboss7-to-wildfly-allow-access-to-servlet-only-from-specific-ips) answer works great at deployment level but I would prefer control at the server-level :

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment only way to do this is by implementing ServletExtension and add extra handlers that will take care of that.

see http://undertow.io/documentation/servlet/servlet-extensions.html for more on writing extensions

and example of using it:
https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow/blob/master/core/src/test/java/io/undertow/server/handlers/IPAddressAccessControlHandlerUnitTestCase.java

In any case I would encourage you to create new feature request in undertow jira to add proper support for this. Issue tracker can be found at: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/UNDERTOW